# Getting db_type() error while using django-facebook connect for DjangoApp

Tags: python, django, facebook, sqlite

I'm using django-1.4 , sqlite3 , django-facebookconnect

Following instructions in Wiki to setup .
"python manage.py syncdb" throws an error .

`Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table blog_post
Creating table blog_comment
Creating table django_admin_log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 91, in handle_noargs
    sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, self.style, seen_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 44, in sql_create_model
    col_type = f.db_type(connection=self.connection)
TypeError: db_type() got an unexpected keyword argument 'connection'`

Is there any solution ??

Comment: Did you not see this comment on the home page of django-facebookconnect: "WARNING: THIS THING IS OBSOLETE - DON'T USE IT - Use this one instead: http://github.com/ryanmark/django_facebook_oauth "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `django-facebook` instead, it does that and more and it is actively supported :)